# не работает lifecycleScope, подсвечивает красным

Tags: android, kotlin, activity-life-cycle, kotlinx-coroutines

не понимаю почему не видит, вроде бы всё подключил.. во всех обучениях которые смотрю всё работает, а у меня нет.. делаю всё также.. в отдельной функции и в отдельном классе пытался, всё также.. и suspend функции пробовал ставить, не помогло, пробовал разные версии lifecycle библиотек подключать не помогло. API 32.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmQDt.png]

Comment: Используй androidx вместо android.support. В студи нажми Refactor -> migrate to androidX. Тогда твоя активити будет наследоватся от androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity, которая уже знает о lifecyclescope.

Comment: Михаил, спасибо, помогло)